# how to invoke a function using refelection

Tags: c#

hi
how to invoke this function using the reflection

for eg:

```
void testFunction(int a , int b , out b)
void testFunction(int a, int b, ref b)
```

Comment: A little context would help.
What have you tried? Where did you run into trouble? Can you show us something approaching a complete class?

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you're after?

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

class Test
{
    public void testFunction1(int a, int b, ref int c)
    {
        c += a + b;
    }

    public void testFunction2(int a, int b, out int c)
    {
        c = a + b;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        MethodInfo method = typeof(Test).GetMethod("testFunction1");
        object[] args = new object[] { 1, 2, 3 };
        Test instance = new Test();
        method.Invoke(instance, args);
        // The ref parameter will be updated in the array, so this prints 6
        Console.WriteLine(args[2]);

        method = typeof(Test).GetMethod("testFunction2");
        // The third argument here has to be of the right type,
        // but the method itself will ignore it
        args = new object[] { 1, 2, 999 };
        method.Invoke(instance, args);
        // The ref parameter will be updated in the array, so this prints 3
        Console.WriteLine(args[2]);
    }
}
```

Note that you have to keep a reference to the array used to specify the arguments, if you want to get at the updated ref/out parameter values afterwards.

If you need non-public methods, you need to specify `BindingFlags` in the call to `GetMethod`.

Comment: suppose i want to invoke using

Comment: mInfo.Invoke(testerclass, new object[] { aNewParam }); second parameter of the fuction is out parameter

Comment: @Ramesh: will provide example using out parameter in 10 minutes when I reach my train station.

Comment: class sample{ int a; int b;  };   class Tester{ void testerfunction( sample a , out b) };

Comment: BindingFlags eFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
                MethodInfo mInfo = typeof(Tester).GetMethod("testerfunction", eFlags);
 mInfo.Invoke(Tester class instance , new object[] { aNewParam });

Comment: in the invoke how to put the out parameter

Comment: @Ramesh: Did you read my comment? There's no point in asking me the same question again while I'm walking to the station with no way of posting. I've now edited the answer to include an example with an out parameter. But you'll have to declare an `object[]` variable separately if you want to get the out parameter afterwards, as shown in my example.

Answer (score 1):

First, that function needs to be a member of a class:

```
class MyClass
{
    public: void testFunction(int a , int b , out b);
}
```

Then, you need an instance of the class:

```
MyClass myObj = new MyClass();
```

Then, use reflection to get the function:

```
MethodInfo[] myMethods = typeof(myObj).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public);
```

Iterate through the methods to find the one you want:

```
MethodInfo myTarget = NULL;
foreach(MethodInfo mi in myMethods)
{
    if (mi.Name == "testFunction")
    {
        myTarget = mi;
        break;
    }
}
```

Finally, invoke it:

```
int[] myParams = {1, 2, 3};
myTarget.Invoke(myObj, (object[])myParams);
```